# How to build project with loging current -xmx -xms

Tags: java, android-studio, gradle

in my /.AndroidStudio2.2/studio64.vmoptions stated
-Xms8192m
-Xmx8192m
-XX:MaxPermSize=1024m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=200m
-XX:+UseCompressedOops

when I run project, just before `Error:java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded` , system monitor shows that all jave related procces use ~4g memory.
[image]
Is there method to log which vmoptions are actually used?

Comment: use jvisualvm or some other tools to inspect memory of your JVM, OS tools are not reliable here